# Stored procedure error : subquery returns more than 1 value

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, subquery, procedure

My problem is that I am getting an error while trying to execute a stored procedure:

> Subquery returns more than 1 value

This is my code:

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE bdfutbol.insertar_equipo (in _nomEquipo varchar(40), in _codLiga char(5),
        in _localidad varchar(60),in _internacional tinyint, out resultadoL TINYINT(1),out resultadoI TINYINT(1)    )
        BEGIN
            set contadorInicial = (select FOUND_ROWS() FROM equipos);
            set resultadoL=(SELECT if (EXISTS (select codLiga from ligas where codLiga=_codLiga),1,0));
            SET resultadoI=0;
            
            if resultadoL=1 THEN 
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO equipos values (null,_nomEquipo,_codliga,_localidad,_internacional);
                    if @contadorInicial!=(select FOUND_ROWS() from equipos) then set resultadoI=1;
                    END IF;
                END;
            END IF;
         END //
DELIMITER;
```

My problem is that I don't know what is causing that error, I have tested all subqueries and they only return one line, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Manage to fix thanks to the advice that found_rows returns rows instead of the count of rounds

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what logic you actually want to implement, but the issue is this logic:

```
if @contadorInicial!=(select FOUND_ROWS() from equipos) then set resultadoI=1;
```

The subquery is selecting as many rows from `equipos` as there are rows in the table.

I don't know what you want to do, but I think more than this line needs fixing.  You might consider asking a new question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to create a procedure that insert x

Comment: isn't ROUND_ROWS() function  deprecated as of MySQL 8.0.17? its better to use COUNT() function instead.